# Node js SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, export

[image]

I'm having the following error in the console when I try to run my api written in node js.

Can you tell me which is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Importing is generally done at the top of your files and looks like this:

```
import User, {schema} from './model.js'
```

Exporting is generally done at the bottom of your files and looks like this:

```
module.exports = {User, schema}
```

Ant the specific reason why you get the error is because `export` is not used that way.

Here is a direct quote from [Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#syntax):

> export DefaultExport from 'bar.js'; // Invalid

Comment: You are mixing CommonJS export syntax with ES6 import syntax. Please don't.

Comment: +1 to @Bergi's comment. This is incorrect. `import` and `export` are ES6. `require` and `module.exports` are CommonJS. The most important thing is consistency. You cannot mix and match. Things will not go well if you do.

Answer (score 5):

You are using ES6 syntax.

Node.js uses common.js syntax

You can use module.export syntax or you can use babel npm package for translate ES6 syntax to common.js syntax

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include a structure you have built, you need to use **import.**
If you want to export a structure that you have edited, you need to use **export.**

Comment: I know, but I don't understand why I get the following error.

Comment: because you exported instead of import.